# Can anyone explain this php code?

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
$a = array('key' => '2');
$a = $a['key'];
var_dump($a);
echo $a['key'], "\n";
?>
```

I expected the code to throw empty string or a warning saying key isn't present, but the code prints 2;

PHP 5.3.10-1

Update1 : Adding var_dump and error_reporting.

Output is

```
hari@hari-laptop:~$ php run.php  
string(1) "2"  
2
```

Comment: Have you enabled corresponding error reporting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$a` is a string that holds the value `"2"`.

Strings in PHP can be indexed to access their characters using square brackets. For example:

```
$a = "abcde";
echo $a[3];  // This will print 'd'
```

When the index is a string, PHP tries to parse it as an integer. If the string is not a number, parsing will give `0`. Hence, The zero'th index, representing the first character is used. (In PHP 5.4 and up, it gives a warning). In your case, you got "2" because `$a['any_stuff']` = first character = `'2'`

From [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> **String access and modification by character**
>
> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying
>   the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using
>   square array brackets, as in `$str[42]`. Think of a string as an array
>   of characters for this purpose. The functions `substr()` and
>   `substr_replace()` can be used when you want to extract or replace more
>   than 1 character.
>
> As of PHP 5.4 string offsets have to either be integers or integer-like strings, otherwise a warning will be thrown.

Comment: Does it mention anywhere that When the index is not a number, it assumes the zero'th index (first character)?

Comment: Wow!!! +1 for new info! :) But wouldn't it throw an error saying that there is no such `index`?

Comment: Excellent answer. It's actually much clearer what's going on if your array value isn't a single character. With `'key'=>'cabbages'`, the output is 'c' and 'cabbages': http://ideone.com/QkhaMp

Comment: @sp2hari: There's a big warning box in that PHP man page that says "Non-integer types are converted to integer". Converting a string (that is not numeric) to an integer gives you `0` (using something like `intval`, for example). *(Added to answer for completeness)*

Answer (score 1):

This makes more sense if you pick a different value for `$a['key']`.

```
$a = array('key' => 'whatever');
$a = $a['key'];
var_dump($a);
echo $a['key'], "\n";
```

Output is:

```
string(8) "whatever"
w
```

First the `echo` command isn't really a function, but a language construct.  The parenthesis are optional.

Secondly, when you have a string which you access as an array, PHP treats the string as an array of characters.  But if you pass an invalid key then you get the first character.

```
echo $a[0];    // w
echo $a[1];    // h
echo $a[2];    // a
echo $a[3];    // t
echo $a['invalid_key'];    // w
```